Knock notification service not working calling from a cron job in NextJS
I am deveolping a web app in React, NextJS and I'm using Knock as notification system for sending in-app notifications when some event happens. In this case i want to send a notification to all users when a report get created.
Reports are created automatically and the function is triggered by a cron job which starts when the app is launched and then executes every week (currently, for testing purposes, every minute).
My problem is, I have created a function which starts the cron and every time it extecutes it creates a fake CSV report (that is saved in the public folder) and then it launches the notification.
Everything works fine, async-await instructions work perfectly but Knock doesn't receive anything, problem is the executions ends correctly, I can't understand why, does anyone have any idea?
Here's the code of the cron:
export const GET = async () => {
    const host = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME;
        
        cron.schedule("* * * * *", async () => {
            const date = new Date();            
            const knock = new Knock(process.env.KNOCK_API_KEY);

            try {
                const csvWriter = createObjectCsvWriter({
                    path: "./public/test.csv",
                    header: [
                        { id: "name", title: "NAME" },
                        { id: "lang", title: "LANGUAGE" },
                        { id: "country", title: "COUNTRY" },
                        { id: "countrys", title: "COUNTRYs" },
                        { id: "langs", title: "LANGUAGEs" },
                        { id: "names", title: "NAMEs" },
                        { id: "countrya", title: "COUNTRYa" },
                        { id: "langa", title: "LANGUAGEa" },
                        { id: "namea", title: "NAMEa" },
                        { id: "paesea", title: "NAMEa" },
                    ],
                });

                const numeroRecord = 1000;

                const records = [];

                // Ciclo for per generare i record
                for (let i = 0; i < numeroRecord; i++) {
                    const record = generaRecordCasuale();
                    records.push(record);
                }

                await csvWriter.writeRecords(records).then(() => {
                    console.log("CSV creato");
                });

                console.log(
                    "CRON JOB: Generazione report - Cron job eseguito " +
                        date +
                        " su istanza: " +
                        process.pid
                );

                await knock.workflows.trigger("reportlink-test", {
                    data: {
                        machinery: "Escavatore EJ-93Y",
                        date: "22/01/2024",
                        url:
                            "http://" +
                            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME +
                            "/macchinari",
                    },
                    recipients: [
                        {
                            id: "1",
                            name: "John Hammond",
                            email: "email@email.it",
                        },
                    ],
                });

            } catch (error) {
                console.log(
                    "CRON JOB: Generazione report - Errore nella generazione del record. " +
                        error
                );
            }
        });
return new Response(
            "CRON JOB: Generazione report - Cron job eseguito con successo.",
            { status: 200 }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return new Response(
            "CRON JOB: Generazione report - Errore nello starting del cron",
            { status: 400 }
        );
    }
};


triggering the function manually (creating a button in front end and calling the same function) in another file route.js works, the notification pops up so is not a code problem (the code is the same), it's not even an API key problem. The server (vs studio since i'm executing in local) console doesn't show any error or warning.
